# Getting the correct Row Index after sorting data with the datagrid

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, datagrid

Whenever I sort the datagrid, the index of the row would still be the index from the datagrid when it wasn't sorted yet. How would I make it so that when I select a row, it would get the index from the newly sorted datagrid?

Here is what I currently have:

```
    Private Sub DataGridView_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView.CellClick
    selectedRow = DataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex
    TextBox1.Text = X_SystemDataSet.Table(selectedRow).Column1
    TextBox2.Text = X_SystemDataSet.Table(selectedRow).Column2
    TextBox3.Text = X_SystemDataSet.Table(selectedRow).Column3
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always add one more column to `DataGridVew`.
Usually as first column, named like xIDx or similar.
Reading value of the cell will bring correct row index.

[image]